# Use Google Scripts to Attach PDF to email

Tags: forms, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to have google Scripts send a PDF as an attachment to an email.  I have a doc template that uses form data that is copied and then filled out.  The code works, but the program keeps sending the template as a pdf and not the filled out copy.  Can anyone help me with this?
Here is some of my code:

```
newDoc = autoWriteNewIEPForm(templateDocId, newDocName, fieldArray, NewEntryArray, submitTeacherName);
newDocId = newDoc.getId();
newDocURL = newDoc.getUrl();
var sender = newEntryArray[0][3];
var subSubject = newDocName;
var subEmailBody = "Thank you for submitting this information.  This receipt confirms that we have received your information." + "<br><br>";
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(newDocId).getAs(MimeType.PDF);
MailApp.sendEmail(sender, subSubject, "", {cc:emailCC, htmlBody:subEmailBody, attachments:[file], name: newDocName});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the last line of your code is correctly attaching the `newDoc` as an attachment. The first line confuses me a bit; `autoWriteNewIEPForm` is not a Google scripts function, and I don't know where you're getting it from or if you're using it correctly. My guess is that you're using it incorrectly, or that for some reason it's not editing any of the text in the `newDoc`, so you have a document that is technically a copy of the template but looks exactly the same.

In the [`Body` class of the Google Scripts `DocumentApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body) you can find a number of methods for editing text in a document's body. I suggest you use one of those instead.